# Gradle caching mechanism

Tags: gradle

It was known a while back that Gradle cached Java modules when doing incremental builds. Meaning modules A, B, & C with changes just done to A, would just require rebuilding of A alone.

However, in reading their [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks) see no mention of module caching. It seems to be more general than so.

Can anyone confirm module was a thing of the past? Also if modules help reduce times with incremental builds nowadays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, tasks provided by Gradle itself (incl. by built-in plugins like `java`) generally try to be incremental, i.e., tasks with up-to-date outputs on disk won’t re-run. See also [this doc section](https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/performance.html#incremental_build) which says:

> Most tasks provided by Gradle take part in incremental build because they have been defined that way.

Comment: Chriki, I'm assuming you're saying yes, packages can be cached just as modules can when doing incremental builds?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean by “packages” and “modules”. The main building block of Gradle incremental builds are _tasks_. Can you maybe elaborate on what you’re after?

Comment: I have a huge project that is divided by 20 Java modules, which were placed to help with build times.  If I refactor the project to 1 module with 20 packages, would incremental build times increase?

Comment: Unless you run your current setup with `--parallel`, I would assume that the build times would roughly remain the same.